# Create functions in function app using terraform code by taking input as zip file of .NET code

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service, terraform-provider-azure

I am using azurerm version of 3.50,
I am using the resource of "azurerm_linux_function_app" and i have zip file generating from .net code.
I am using a parameter named "zip_deploy_file" that supports zip format as {path.module}/functions.zip.
The problem here is, there is no error to show you... but in the same time functions are also not creating.
I have tried via storage account but need to achieve via "zip_deploy_file" pls suggest...

Comment: Can you please provide more info regarding the terraform code you tried and zip file and its Structure.

Comment: zip file is generating by npm build of .Net code coming as artifacts and utilizing that zip using "zip_deploy_file" parameter. thanks for the response

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when I´ve tried to config a windows function app and I ended creating the function through the azurerm_function_app_function resource.

You can use it to upload the required files (with the file argument), define the input/output bindings using the config_json argument, etc. Have you already tried it?

Comment: Hi, azurerm_function_app_function will be deprecated soon in version 4.. so that i am not using azurerm_function_app_function.. Thanks for the response

Comment: Where have you seen this information? In the official documentation I couldn´t see anything related and normally it appears at the first lines.

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/3.65.0/docs/resources/function_app_function